# Como puedo hallar el porcentaje entre dos números con JS - Jquery

Tags: javascript, lógica

Buenas Tardes titanes de la programación tengo una duda, estoy usando una librería con un progress bar que va subiendo según el porcentaje [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dentro del codigo lo tengo en 60%.

en la base de datos tengo 2 valores que son `golpes` y `golpes-totales` , quiero hacer que me calcule cuanto `%` va `golpes` siendo `golpes-totales` el `100%` , suponiendo que tengo 5000 en `golpes-totales`  y en `golpes` 574.

Muchas gracias por compartir su conocimiento :)

Comment: Deberias agregar tu codigo.

Comment: No es necesario realmente ya que solo necesito sacar el porcentaje de un numero total según una variable, por ejemplo tengo 85 de 100 es el 85% de 100.

Comment: Seria mas facil si pudiera ver el nombre de tus variables.  Por ejemplo, javascript no permite tener dash en el nombre.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es una regla de 3 simple...

```
var porcentaje= (golpes / golpes-totales)*100;
```

si necesitas la parte entera

```
var intPorcentaje = Math.round( porcentaje );
```

En tu ejemplo:

```
( 574 / 5000 ) * 100 = 11.48%
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me funciono muy bien :)

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que solo necesitas la fórmula para sacar el porcentaje de una cantidad solo agregas el valor de la siguiente fórmula a una variable:

```
var result = (35.8 / 100) * 5000;
```

En el ejemplo estoy mostrando el %35.8 de la cantidad 5000.
Espero te ayude.